# how to use decimal values in Math.pow()

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a calculation:

```
 (22,582 / 10,000)^1/15 - 1
```

In **C#** I am using like this:

```
double i = Math.Pow(2.2582,1/15) - 1;
Response.Write(i);
```

But everytime it returns me **0** in **i**. I know (**1/15**) is making some disturbance in the calculation, so to solve this I used (**.067**) in place of (**1/15**) which gives me result **0.0560927980835855**, but I am still far away from my actual result. Can somebody please tell the right approach.

Comment: I think you are missing a power operator (^) in the first calculation: `(22,582 / 10,000)^(1/15) - 1`, Otherwise the two calculations are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first calculation should be:

```
(22.582d / 10.000d) * (1.0d/15.0d) - 1.0d
```

You use the "d" in literals to tell the compiler that the number should be a double. If you don't use it the compiler thinks that 1/15 is two integers divided resulting in 0.

So the last calculation should be:

```
double i = Math.Pow(2.2582d, 1.0d/15.0d) - 1.0d;
Response.Write(i);
```

This means that:

```
1/15 = 0
```

and

```
1.0d/15.0d = 0.06666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Here 1 and 15 are considered as integers and were calculated to find the integer result 1/15 =0;
not the double result.
Try using 1f/15f instead of 1/15